# Angular 4 tooling - reducing operations to test and run

Tags: angular, build, automated-tests, webpack-dev-server, build-tools

My development setup for Angular 4 currently looks like this:

- Text editor for making changes
- Console window running `ng test` to check unit test results via Karma on each save
- Console window running `ng serve` to provide an accessible web serve for exploratory testing (I believe this is running the same webpack-dev-server module I use standalone when I'm working with React rather than Angular (?))
- Console window for running `ng e2e` to run end-to-end automated tests via Protractor (which I need to do manually - is there no way to have protractor run when the source changes?)
- Browser window for viewing unit test results
- Browser window for exploratory testing
- Browser window for viewing end-to-end test results (which I need to open manually again)

This is an awful lot of windows, and I'm wondering if there is any way of reducing it at all.  It seems reasonable that there ought to be a workflow where:

- On save, the unit tests are run immediately.  The results are pushed to a browser tab.
- If the unit tests are successful, webpack runs and updates the currently available version on the development server.
- Once the development server has an update from webpack, protractor is automatically run.  Results are pushed to the same browser tab as the Karma tests.
- Ideally, all this could be integrated with my text editor (which is currently Atom).

Any suggestions of how I can achieve any of this? Or other approaches that might trim down how much I'm having to run at once?

Comment: A thought about a possible approach: `webpack` is a pretty expandable system, and there are a variety of existing plugins for it that do all kinds of stuff (plus I believe it's fairly easy to write your own plugin), so a *lot* of this could probably be done just by injecting a couple of plugins to webpack... but where is the webpack configuration used by Angular CLI?  It isn't in any of the files that were created by `ng new`, so how do `ng serve` et al know how to build the project?

Comment: ... also, I see a lot of discussion on how to get various test frameworks to run *after* a webpack build (so they can use the webpack-processed bundle to run, thus reducing variations from the deployed environment... I don't really see the point in this, though: unit tests are supposed to run isolated from stuff you deploy them with, that's the point!), but are there any existing webpack plugins that would let you run the tests *before* the build?

Comment: Ok, turns out that [the webpack config is intentionally not exposed to modification](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656), so integrating via webpack plugins is clearly not going to work.